# how to ignore <sub></sub> tag from xml file? please see example

Tags: php, xml

Here is the **XML** file let's say `$xml;`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <btps>
   <u5_SO2>
      <label>Sulphur Dioxide (SO<sub>2</sub>)</label>
      <value>..</value>
      <unit>mg/Nm<super>3</super></unit>
   </u5_SO2>
   <u5_NO2>
      <label>Nitrogen Dioxide (NO<sub>2</sub>)</label>
      <value>..</value>
      <unit>mg/Nm<super>3</super></unit>
   </u5_NO2>
  </btps>
```

Here is the **PHP** script

```
$label = $xml->u5_SO2->label;
$value = $xml->u5_SO2->value;
$unit = $xml->u5_SO2->unit;

echo "<br>".$label;
echo "<br>".$value; 
echo "<br>".$unit;
```

when i echo this `$label` variable it printing like this **Sulphur
Dioxide (SO)** but what I accept is **Sulphur Dioxide (SO2)**  is it possible to print what I accepted?

Comment: The structure is strange, it actually feels like an encoding error rather than an intended design. Is the file something you generate or you're just dealing with third-party data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a regex to find and remove the element. Like it

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <btps>
   <u5_SO2>
      <label>Sulphur Dioxide (SO<sub>2</sub>)</label>
      <value>..</value>
      <unit>mg/Nm<super>3</super></unit>
   </u5_SO2>
   <u5_NO2>
      <label>Nitrogen Dioxide (NO<sub>2</sub>)</label>
      <value>..</value>
      <unit>mg/Nm<super>3</super></unit>
   </u5_NO2>
  </btps>';

$xml = preg_replace('/(<sub>)(.*)?(<\/sub>)/', '$2', $xml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$label = $xml->u5_SO2->label;
$value = $xml->u5_SO2->value;
$unit = $xml->u5_SO2->unit;

echo "<br>".$label . PHP_EOL;
echo "<br>".$value . PHP_EOL;
echo "<br>".$unit . PHP_EOL;
```

Check in codepad
http://codepad.org/SbmbmGFl

---

You else, can put it back when parse the element like that

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <btps>
   <u5_SO2>
      <label>Sulphur Dioxide (SO<sub>2</sub>)</label>
      <value>..</value>
      <unit>mg/Nm<super>3</super></unit>
   </u5_SO2>
   <u5_NO2>
      <label>Nitrogen Dioxide (NO<sub>2</sub>)</label>
      <value>..</value>
      <unit>mg/Nm<super>3</super></unit>
   </u5_NO2>
  </btps>';

$xml = preg_replace('/(<sub>)(.*)?(<\/sub>)/', '___sub___$2___sub___', $xml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml as $row) {
    $row->label = preg_replace('/(___sub___)(.*)?(___sub___)/', '<sub>$2</sub>', $row->label);
}

$label = $xml->u5_SO2->label;
$value = $xml->u5_SO2->value;
$unit = $xml->u5_SO2->unit;

echo "<br>".$label . PHP_EOL;
echo "<br>".$value . PHP_EOL;
echo "<br>".$unit . PHP_EOL;
```

Check in codepad
http://codepad.org/mvnJYnGB

Comment: The second example just works perfectly. thanks a lot, mate

Answer (score 4):

SimpleXML is not a good option if you have mixed type child nodes. With current DOM this is a lot easier because it allows for precise node manipulations. Use Xpath expressions to fetch nodes and DOM methods to manipulate them.

DOM nodes have a property `textContent` which allows you to read (and write) all descendant text nodes as a string.

Here is an example that replaces elements with text nodes (with unicode characters):

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$replacements = [
  '//sub' => ['2' => "\u{2082}", '3' => "\u{2083}" /*,...*/],
  '//super' => ['2' => "\u{00B2}", '3' => "\u{00B3}" /*,...*/]
];

foreach ($replacements as $expression => $map) {
    // fetch and iterate nodes
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $sub) {
        $content = $sub->textContent;
        // check map
        if (isset($map[$content])) {
            // replace element with text node 
            $sub->parentNode->replaceChild(
               $document->createTextNode($map[$content]),
               $sub
            );
        }
    } 
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<btps>
   <u5_SO2>
      <label>Sulphur Dioxide (SO&#x2082;)</label>
      <value>..</value>
      <unit>mg/Nm&#xB3;</unit>
   </u5_SO2>
   <u5_NO2>
      <label>Nitrogen Dioxide (NO&#x2082;)</label>
      <value>..</value>
      <unit>mg/Nm&#xB3;</unit>
   </u5_NO2>
  </btps>
```

Reading the modified DOM with Xpath expressions:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/btps/*') as $element) {
    var_dump(
        [
            'label' => $xpath->evaluate('string(label)', $element),
            'value' => $xpath->evaluate('string(value)', $element),
            'unit' => $xpath->evaluate('string(unit)', $element),
        ]
    );
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["label"]=>
  string(23) "Sulphur Dioxide (SO₂)"
  ["value"]=>
  string(2) ".."
  ["unit"]=>
  string(7) "mg/Nm³"
}
array(3) {
  ["label"]=>
  string(24) "Nitrogen Dioxide (NO₂)"
  ["value"]=>
  string(2) ".."
  ["unit"]=>
  string(7) "mg/Nm³"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would argue in favor of using DOMDocument over SimpleXML, in favor of using xpath over dot notation and against regex in xml under any circumstances.

So with that said, after the usual DOMDocument boilerplate, I would use this:

```
$label = $xpath->evaluate('//u5_SO2/label')[0];
echo $label->textContent;
```

Output:

```
Sulphur Dioxide (SO2)
```

Comment: You can shorten that to `echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//u5_SO2/label)');` and avoid missing node errors.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using SimpleXML. I don't think you can't easily do it with that extension alone, but you can use it together with DOMDocument ([dom_import_simplexml()](https://www.php.net/dom_import_simplexml) and [DOMNode::nodeValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue)):

```
dom_import_simplexml($xml->u5_SO2->label)->nodeValue
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PPudt).